# Comparando Variables Categóricas en R

Tags: r, rstudio, plot, categorical

Comparar automáticamente todas las variables categóricas de un dataframe en R es muy importante. Para simplificar el problema por favor asuma que todas las variables del dataframe son categóricas.

Como ejemplo crearé un dataframe que llamaremos df_categorical y está formado por las variables categóricas Sex, Pclass, y Survived del conjunto de datos Titanic.

Para atacar este problema, he leído que muchos autores, como por ejemplo Paul Murrell en su libro R Graphics, consideran que un ***mosaic plot*** sería lo más adecuado.

```
library(titanic)
library(tidyverse)
data(titanic_train)
str(titanic_train)
df_categorical <- titanic_train %>% 
  mutate(Survived = factor(Survived), Pclass = factor(Pclass), Sex = factor(Sex)) %>%
  select(Survived, Pclass, Sex)
str(df_categorical)
library(vcd)
pairs(structable(df_categorical))
```

[image: Mosaic Plot library(vcd)]

***Sin embargo, preferiría porcentajes en lugar de totales.***
También desearía colores.

***Puedo obtenerlo manualmente usando cada posible subconjunto con la librería plotluck de Stefan Schroedl*** @stefan.schroedl. Sin embargo, me interesa una solución automática para cualquier dataframe que tenga ***solamente*** variables categóricas. Este plot si tiene porcentajes. ***Sin embargo, tengo q usar los nombres de las variables. Algo que no quiero hacer :(:(:(*** Podrían por favor ayudarme? De antemano, muchas gracias!

```
install.packages('devtools')
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("stefan-schroedl/plotluck")
library(plotluck)
plotluck(df_categorical, Survived~Pclass)
```

[image: Plotluck Stefan Schroedl]

***Otra posibilidad que he estado pensando***  es encontrar los subsets de 2 elementos y graficar esos plots, ***uno después de otro-es decir individualmente***, usando plotluck. Por ejemplo si el dataframe tiene 3 variables: {1,2},{1,3}, {2,3}.  Dataframe de 4 variables: {1,2}, {1,3}, {1,4}, {2,3}, {2,4}. Y así sucesivamente.

Sin embargo, para 5 variables son 10 subsets. Para 6 variables, 15 subsets. Etc. Parece algo imposible, pero es lo que se logra con

```
library(vcd)
pairs(structable(df_categorical))
```

[image: Número de Subsets de 2 elementos]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que estás usando el paquete `vcd`, deberías aprovechar la función `mosaic()` que justamente grafica las tablas de contingencia como la que has construido, `pairs()` en realidad está orientada a comparar nubes de puntos.

```
# Creamos una tabla de contingencia 
# Es más cómodo así (en vez de usar structable) a la hora de armar los porcentajes
tabla <- table(df_categorical)
# Creamos la tabla de porcentajes
porcentajes <- prop.table(tabla)
porcentajes[] <- sprintf("%.1f%%",round(porcentajes*100, 3))

# Dibujamos el mosico    
mosaic(tabla, shade = TRUE, pop = FALSE)
# Etiquetamos con el porcentaje, cada celda
labeling_cells(text = porcentajes, margin = 0)(tabla)
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El criterio de "coloreado" en este caso es automático y determinado por una medida estadística, puedes ver más documentación sobre esto en las [viñetas del paquete](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vcd/vignettes/residual-shadings.pdf). De todas formas, puedes reconfigurar los colores de manera arbitraria:

```
color <- c("#f48f8b","#52c7cb")
mosaic(tabla, gp = gpar(fill = color),  pop = FALSE)
labeling_cells(text = porcentajes, margin = 0)(tabla)
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Excelente respuesta!

Comment: Una pregunta. Esta opción solamente funcionará para 3 variables, correcto? Q pasaría con 4 variables o más?

Comment: Hola @Beginner, funciona perfectamente para más variables, seguramente a medida que aumentes estas, la "legibilidad" del gráfico se complique.

Comment: Genial! Nuevamente gracias por la respuesta!